# MySQL dynamic SQL procedure unknown syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error, dynamic-sql

Having trouble with this stored procedure. Been at it for at least 4 hours, and still, no luck.

It creates the procedure no problem, but, when trying to call it, it throws a syntax error with no clues where to find the mistake. (Syntax error near '').

I'm using MySQL 5.6.39, and as client, HeidiSQL 9.5.0.5196

Edit: The purpose of this procedure, is to calculate the average time from another table, ignoring the outliers, that's why I used so many temp tables.
Thanks again!

Here's the code

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tiempoPromedioUsuarioP;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE tiempoPromedioUsuarioP (IN current_user_id INT, IN outliers FLOAT(4,3), OUT promedio_segundos INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    SET @s1 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tp',current_user_id, ' (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, sesion_log.init_date, sesion_log.end_date) AS tiempoPromedio FROM sesion_log WHERE sesion_log.id_usuario = ', current_user_id, ' AND sesion_log.is_end = 1;');
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

    SET @s2 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE boundsA',current_user_id,' (SELECT (AVG(tp',current_user_id,'.tiempoPromedio) - STD(tp',current_user_id,'.tiempoPromedio)*',outliers,') AS lb FROM tp',current_user_id,');');
    PREPARE stmt2 FROM @s2;
    EXECUTE stmt2;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

    SET @s3 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE boundsB',current_user_id,' (SELECT (AVG(tp',current_user_id,'.tiempoPromedio) + STD(tp',current_user_id,'.tiempoPromedio)*',outliers,') AS ub FROM tp',current_user_id,');');
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @s3;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

    SET @s4 = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE res',current_user_id,' SELECT round(AVG(tp',current_user_id,'.tiempoPromedio)) as promedio FROM tp WHERE tp',current_user_id,'.tiempoPromedio BETWEEN (SELECT lb FROM boundsA',current_user_id,') AND (SELECT ub FROM boundsB',current_user_id,');');
    PREPARE stmt4 FROM @s4;
    EXECUTE stmt4;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;

    SET @s5 = CONCAT('
        DECLARE promedioc CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM res',current_user_id,'; 

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 

        OPEN promedioc;

        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH promedioc INTO promedio_segundos;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE promedioc;
    ');
    PREPARE stmt5 FROM @s5;
    EXECUTE stmt5;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5;

    SET @s6 = CONCAT('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tp',current_user_id);
    PREPARE stmt6 FROM @s6;
    EXECUTE stmt6;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt6;

    SET @s7 = CONCAT('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE boundsA',current_user_id);
    PREPARE stmt7 FROM @s7;
    EXECUTE stmt7;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt7;

    SET @s8 = CONCAT('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE boundsB',current_user_id);
    PREPARE stmt8 FROM @s8;
    EXECUTE stmt8;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt8;

    SET @s9 = CONCAT('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE res',current_user_id);
    PREPARE stmt9 FROM @s9;
    EXECUTE stmt9;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt9;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only declare variables in a stored program , when you submit code using dynamic sql this rule has to be obeyed , you are breaking it in  SET s5 = ... Also if memory serves dynamic sql can only execute 1 statement not a bunch of them as you have here. SET s5 =needs a rethink.

Comment: oooh! didn't know that, I'm new to this procedure stuff. So, I cannot have a cursor pointed to a variable name table? It was too good to be true. Thanks for your answer P.Salmon!